# SQL Server Reporting Services - output subreports to individual files

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a parent report that generates a series of subreports. After clicking the preview button, I can see the final report built with the actual data, and I may print it or save it to file. File may be a MS Word doc, a PDF or others. Perfect. I can do that individually to each report I need. My problem: I have a base report that will run a subreport several times. Instead of having them all in a big PDF file as output, I need to save each individual subreport as a file separately. Otherwise, I will have to run these subreports individually each at a time, which will eat up a lot of time, besides being more error prone. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the typo on the title, how can I change this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a subscription for each sub report to save a PDF to a file share?